# Should the [compensation] tag be removed?

Tags: discussion, tag-blacklist

There are 8 questions tagged with [compensation](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/compensation) and 5 are closed.

Also, compensation is *literally* off-topic according to the FAQ: *salary or compensation*

The 3 questions that remain open seem as if they are appropriate for this site, but I am a bit conflicted given that the FAQ explicitly forbids them. Are these special cases, or are these now considered off-topic? If they are off-topic, should we blacklist the [compensation](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/compensation) tag all together?

As a side note, there is no [salary](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/salary) tag. I don't know if it ever existed or  was addressed in the past.

---

I have edited the tag out of all the closed questions. Here is the list of them for reference:

- [Why do business analysts and project managers get higher salaries than programmers?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/45776/why-do-business-analysts-and-project-managers-get-higher-salaries-than-programme)
- [Is it possible/likely to be paid fairly without a college degree?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/70377/is-it-possible-likely-to-be-paid-fairly-without-a-college-degree)
- [Salary Negotiation; How Best to Broach the Subject?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/127775/salary-negotiation-how-best-to-broach-the-subject)
- [Is there any site which tells or highlights by zone developer income source? I think i am getting less yearly](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/132346/is-there-any-site-which-tells-or-highlights-by-zone-developer-income-source-i-t)
- [Jobs asking for web design and development skills, should it be doubling the pay?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/137928/jobs-asking-for-web-design-and-development-skills-should-it-be-doubling-the-pay)

I don't think any of these questions should be reopened. They are basically consulting a programmers perspective, and not really about software development. At least that's how I am interpreting them against the FAQ. I'll report on the other open questions when I have time to really digest them.

Comment: blacklisting involves regular expressions, thus _no one wants to do it_. ;P

Comment: Haha, fair enough! I only suggest blacklisting it because it is literally mentioned in the FAQ as off-topic. I didn't realize, as @ChrisF pointed out, that just removing it would prevent it from showing up in the suggestion box.

Answer (score 8):

If you think that the questions that are still open are appropriate then simply edit them to remove the tag.

We can edit and reopen or delete the closed questions (as appropriate) to remove the tag completely from the system.

Once the tag has been removed from all live questions it won't be suggested to people when they enter the tags for their question. This should discourage it's use. However, if the tag reappears *then* we can consider blacklisting.

Answer (score 3):

Compensation falls under `freelancing and business concerns` though so it also on topic.

I'm not saying all compensation question should be allowed with this line of thought, just that not all possible questions where a compensation tag would work are off topic, there is a set probably a really small one that this tag would work for.

Comment: You bring up a good point. My interpretation was that since "salary and compensation" was specifically mentioned as off-topic, then the set of those questions was not included in "freelancing and business concerns". Maybe the FAQ could be clarified? I wonder what the intended scope of "freelancing and business concerns" was...

Comment: @JeremyHeiler I'm not sure how far reaching it is, it seems like 90%+ of questions that would fall in this category are generally closed.